# Переход на другую страницу без обновления

Tags: jquery, html, css

Здравствуйте. Как сделать переход на другую страницу без обновления обшей страницы . 
Сайт видео хостинг . Как сделать чтобы при клике на видео переход не осуществлялся на другую страницу . Что то типа vube . Смог сделать с помощью toggle,fade но не то как то . Спасибо за внимание .

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".container-fluid").css("display", "none");

$(".container-fluid").toggle('slide');

$(".pm-thumb-fix pm-thumb-14").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    linkLocation = this.href;
    $(".container-fluid").toggle(1000, redirectPage, 'slide');
});

function redirectPage() {
    window.location = linkLocation;
}

});
```

Comment: это делается через history api. Есть еще универсальные библиотеки типа https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/ в целом процесс такой - получаете текущий state и на его основе делаете запрос ajax к своему серверу (либо достаете из кэша), как подгрузили, ставите новый контент, например справа от текущего, и скроллите влево.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию.В целом понятно что нужно использовать ajax. Но именно как не понимаю. Можете показать пример ?

Comment: там в основном не ajax, а history api, ajax только для получения данных.

Comment: не понял как сделать . Можете какой нибудь пример показать ? У меня сейчас так при клике ".pm-thumb-fix pm-thumb-14" переходит на другую страницу (watch.php?vid=)

Comment: я готового примера не нашел, а кодить не хочу, просто делайте типа `$('#next').load(url)`; и сдвигайте его влево, вот и все. [здесь я давно писал пример для history.js](http://doduts.comoj.com/) но там без эффектов.

Comment: Спасибо .Думал с не load() надо делать .

Comment: сделал как то по другому вот код 
   $(document).ready(function() {

$('.pm-thumb-145').click(function(){
$('.popup').show(500);
$('.hover').show();

        
var url=$(this).attr('href');
$('.popup').load(url);
return false;
});
$('.hover').click(function(){
    $('.popup').hide('fast');
    $('.hover').hide();
    
} );



});